# Is Genetic Algorithm a Machine Learning Method?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am curious about the logic behind machine learning term. As my understanding, Q Learning is a machine learning. Because it learns a concept. It learns states.
But when it comes to genetic algorithms, i don't see them as machine learning. To me, these algorithms are just a way of optimizing a specific problem. If environment changes(states), precalculated genetic algorithm based solution will be useless. You have to run it again.

So the question is, Is Genetic Algorithm a Machine Learning Method?

All the replies will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the AI/ML classification are quite clear and see Genetic Algorithms as an ML method. [Deepdive in AIML venture landscape By Ajit Nazre Rahul Garg](https://www.slideshare.net/ajitnazre/deepdive-in-aiml-venture-landscape-by-ajit-nazre-rahul-garg/3)
[image]

Comment: Yeah i can see that tree clearly. But like i mentioned in the question, i am troubling with the logic. Almost all of the methods shown in this tree has a strong side for a particular problem type. But what about genetic algorithms? We can use it, maybe for a snake game agent training process, but is it a real learning process? If it is, that means i miss the meaningfull use case of this algorithm. I would like to hear your ideas rather than that tree :)

Comment: I think you struggle with the term "learning". It is a technical term, with a specific meaning/definition in the AI/ML realm. And I think you can justify this definition of "learning". This is the pragmatic view of this _problem_. Whether it is "a real learning process", is a rather philosophical question. Which is also very interesting, by the way. You can see a GA as "just and optimization method" or a "learning method". I think you can find arguments for both views. The pragmatic answer is: the AI community decided to put it into the "Unsupervised Learning" methods, which is also not wrong.

Comment: "If it is, that means i miss the meaningfull use case of this algorithm", yes you do miss use cases. They can be great when you can't use supervised learning, for example when you are not able to evaluate a single output from another ML technique, because you don't know how good solutions look like, but you may be able to say "solution 1 is better than solution 2".

Comment: Solutions can be hole algorithms. It's all depends on how you encode it into genes. For example you could easily represent neural nets (with fixed topology) with genes, because they are just a collection of numbers. Other algorithms may be more complicated and its not allways trivial and the more complex the representation is, the less likely it is that it works well, but it's hard to tell without trying.